# Observing a planet without contaminating it in anyway?

Tags: xenobiology, space-travel

There is a planet called Galileo with life on it. The life is getting extremely complex, in fact, with some of the life on Galileo beginning to form tribes and clans and learning language. Humans want to study this planet, themselves in person (No drones or robots) but they want to keep this planet in as pristine conditions possible. As little contamination as possible, if any at all. My question is, how can they go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you talk about contamination, are you speaking about biological contamination, or cultural contamination?

As far as biological contamination goes, it should be fairly simple for any human society advanced enough for space travel, just make sure that any exits out to the planet's surface (through buildings or out of ships) are kept behind airlocks with decontamination showers built in, and make it compulsory for people heading out to wear hazmat gear. This is especially simple if the planet doesn't have an atmosphere that's breathable to humans, since airlocks and space suits (effectively hazmat suits) are already necessary. Additionally when it comes to the ships themselves, the cold vacuum of space followed by the intense heat of reentry really ought to be enough to keep the outside of the ship sterile. This probably goes without saying, but they'd also need to restrict any unauthorized ships from landing on the surface, because they might not be fitted with the proper gear, generally the fewer people and groups are there, the lower the likelihood of a containment breach.

In terms of cultural contamination, this is much harder, seeing as any kind of contact with an outside force would be enough to drastically change the way any civilization forms, especially if the members are already intelligent enough to form language and tribes. If the humans or their sci-fi  technology are ever seen, expect them to be worshipped as gods. If humans wanted to avoid cultural contamination, but also wanted to see the aliens in person, they would have to take extreme precautions, making sure any permanent or semi-permanent encampment they made was remote and far away from any kind of alien settlement, additionally, they would need some kind of cloaking technology, and I wouldn't expect them to ever get much closer than a few kilometers away from any settlement, always watching from afar.

Answer (score 4):

### Very difficult if you were there, possible if you weren't

Contamination can occur in many ways. Through our biology, through interaction, and through detection.

**Through Fungal Spores and Bacteria**

Probably the best known and most obvious one is biological contamination, being transmission of bacteria and fungal spores. The unfortunate thing is, it is almost impossible to currently eradicate bacteria from our spaceships.

The Mars Exploration Rovers [are the 'cleanest' available probes we currently have](https://www.nasa.gov/missions/solarsystem/mer_clean.html), with NASA having 'strict' sterilisation requirements of 300,000 spores, or 300 spores / square metre. This of course is not zero, and it is almost impossible to reduce it to zero unless your spacecraft is created wholly in space using material not from Earth, and for there to be no landing in any Earth environment (our [atmosphere is saturated with fungal spores and bacteria](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166111608700700)) during its operation.

There is [already speculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interplanetary_contamination) that our current probes to Mars, even with these requirements, would have already contaminated that planet such that detection of life there must be viewed first as life from Earth, eliminating this possibility first, rather than assuming it is indigenous.

Even the smallest exposure of just one of these spores would possibly contaminate your planet if the conditions are right. The single spore could float in their atmosphere, and multiply when it reaches ideal environments. This, of course, may be catastrophic to your alien planet. You can also forget about spacesuits or airlocks - fungal and bacteria spores will get through these areas easily.

**Through Interaction**

The biological contamination risk being too high, *it is unlikely any physical contact is possible without advanced planning from both sides*.

This means 'communication' must occur through technology that does not require physical interaction.

The common sci-fi trope of clashing cultures makes good viewing, but unfortunately is very unlikely. Forget about getting aliens pregnant, an Oak tree is a closer relative to us than the aliens, so it simply isn't possible. Cultural contamination assumes we are communicating, and now if remote it really requires a common protocol and language/grammatical structure. Both would need to work really hard at it to achieve even just talking.

**Detection**

Of course it may be possible simply to observe this culture in ways that we could remain undetected, and remote. This would be preferable. *Stealthy ultra-accurate [spy satellites](https://www.fastcompany.com/40510108/new-low-cost-spy-satellites-are-getting-scarily-powerful) come to mind*, perhaps even ones that could detect movement, sound, distance and material, such that a virtual VR World can be generated for us to walk around in.

*Any satellite transmissions need to be focussed to prevent detection*, as simply being detected could also 'contaminate' (imagine if we found one in our orbit, and the biggest questions in our universe are suddenly answered).

Once ready, and interaction is (for whatever reason) desirable, perhaps sending robots to the planet (that are made in space) would be best, being installed with AI that already knows how to communicate. Or they are controlled through VR by humans remotely.